# How can I append elements to different arrays via a for-loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have this piece of code:

```
Lista_enteros = []
Lista_texto = []

def recibir(*args):
    argumentos = args
    return argumentos

filtrar_args = recibir("Hola mundo", 6)

for i in filtrar_args:
    if type(i) == "<class 'int'>":
        Lista_enteros.append(i)
    else:
        Lista_texto.append(i)

print (Lista_enteros)
print(Lista_texto)
```

I expected to have an output like this:

```
[6]
['Hola mundo']
```

But when I execute the code, I'm getting this printed:

```
[]
['Hola mundo', 6]
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :`if isinstance(i, int)` instead of :`if type(i) == "<class 'int'>":`

Try this:

```
Lista_enteros = []
Lista_texto = []

def recibir(*args):
    argumentos = args
    return argumentos

filtrar_args = recibir("Hola mundo", 6)

for i in filtrar_args:
    if isinstance(i, int):
        Lista_enteros.append(i)
    else:
        Lista_texto.append(i)

print (Lista_enteros)
print(Lista_texto)
```

Output:

```
[6]
['Hola mundo']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line -

if type(i) == "<class 'int'>"

to

if type(i) == int:

Answer (score -1):

`<class int>` is the output of the toString method of the type `int`. What you want is actually:

```py
if type(i) is int:
  ...
```